# Web Crawling Using Python Request with Cookies Enabled

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl this specific web page:
https://www.grainger.com/category/abrasives/abrasive-blasting/abrasive-blasting-cabinets

Using the following code line:

```
page = requests.get("https://www.grainger.com/category/abrasives/abrasive-blasting/abrasive-blasting-cabinets")
```

However, the page comes with default "table" view. But the web page I want to crawl is when the "list view is enabled. How can I request the web page with "list" view enabled as shown in the picture below:
[image: u]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the network tab from Google Chrome, it seems to me that this website knows which view shows by setting a cookie, so you may set this cookie in your request if you want to view as a list.

```
requests.get("https://www.grainger.com/category/abrasives/abrasive-blasting/abrasive-blasting-cabinets", cookies={'pv':'list'})
```

In future you can check [this reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference) to help you know what is actually happening while you are browsing.